# How to avoid duplicating complicated catch blocks

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
try {
    do_stuff();
    return do_more_stuff();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    throw new CustomException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw CustomException.unexpected_error(e);
}
```

I now need to have all those catch blocks in another similar function. What is the best way to avoid duplication here?

Note that the code inside the two try blocks is not very similar.

Also I can't really put the set of catches higher up.

Note, I'd prefer to avoid:

```
try {
    do_stuff();
    return do_more_stuff();
} catch (Exception e) {
    handle_exception_via_rtti(e);
}
```

Comment: why do you want to avoid the rtti version?

Comment: As dpb says "If your code just catches Exception, and the do_stuff and do_more_stuff later add extra checked exceptions, you'll probably never know about the change and the fact that your code could now be wrong."

Comment: Personally, I'd just have your method throw the original exceptions.  You don't do much with your catch blocks to 'handle' anything except wrapping in a CustomException.  What value is that adding?

Comment: These two functions are used heavily. The new exception allows more descriptive error handling for users of my library in the context of the library's use thus allowing them to write more robust code.

Comment: I can't agree. An IOException is an IOException. There is just no point in wrapping it. Ditto a SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: There are always exceptions, in this case it makes sense. You can disagree all you want, but you haven't seen all the code and you don't know the context. Trying not to write custom exceptions is indeed generally a good rule. I didn't take this choice lightly. For the code I am writing, and considering how it will be used, it makes sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I'd try to make the

```
do_stuff();
return do_more_stuff();
```

part conform to a more general format in order to apply Strategy (as a pattern).

Then you can refactor all the places where you call this kind of block so that they can call a more generalized block (where the catches are laid out just once).

Comment: Indeed the strategy pattern will work here. For future generations, this would involve replacing `do_stuff(); return do_more_stuff()` with `return strategy.do_stuff()`. Thus you pass strategy to your exception handler function. This pattern would require all strategies to return the same type from do_stuff();

Comment: I didn't understand the explanation. Code example would have been useful.

Answer (score 5):

> *Note, I'd prefer to avoid:*

Then either just live with it, or wait until JDK7 comes with [Multicatch](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#catch) so that you can rewrite like:

```
try {
    do_stuff();
    return do_more_stuff();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | ProtocolException | MalformedURLException e) {
    throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    throw new CustomException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw CustomException.unexpected_error(e);
}
```

You can alternatively also move this into the constructor of `CustomException` and do a (nasty) global catch, but then you'll need to add a bunch of (nasty) `if/else` blocks to determine the type of the exception cause. All with all, I'd just prefer to stick with the way as you already did.

**Update**: another alternative is to split/refactor the lines which can potentially throw the exception as separate tasks into another method blocks throwing `CustomException`. E.g.

```
try {
    do_stuff_with_encoding();
    do_stuff_with_url();
    do_stuff_with_ws();
    // ...
    return do_more_stuff();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    throw new CustomException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw CustomException.unexpected_error(e);
}

...

public SomeObject do_stuff_with_encoding() throws CustomException {
    try {
        do_stuff();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
    }
}  

public SomeObject do_stuff_with_url() throws CustomException {
    try {
        do_stuff();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
    }
}  

public SomeObject do_stuff_with_ws() throws CustomException {
    try {
        do_stuff();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC: Unfortunately, that proposal was rejected: http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five (Unless someone here can correct me on this..)

Comment: @Tim: It's now being reconsidered for inclusion http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/entry/projec_coin_post_devoxx_closures

Comment: @Tim: let's really hope it. This has encountered me (although only a few) times as well.

Comment: FYI: the multicatch proposal **made** it into Java 7: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: This shows that there is no real work around yet if the java language has to be changed to accomodate these cases.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of why the `do_stuff` and `do_more_stuff` throw the checked exceptions. Are they doing that to force the user to treat the exception? If yes, then you trying to avoid:

```
try {
    do_stuff();
    return do_more_stuff();
} catch (Exception e) {
    handle_exception_via_rtti(e);
}
```

is a good thing.

If your code just catches `Exception`, and the  `do_stuff` and `do_more_stuff` later add extra exceptions, you'll probably never know about the change and the fact that your code could now be wrong.

So you might have to deal with [throwing the kitchen sink](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html) and treat all those exceptions, unless the methods could switch to unchecked exceptions.

On the other hand, if the methods are throwing checked exceptions just because the programmer was lazy in treating with them and just wanted to pass the buck, maybe you are looking at this from the wrong angle.

Comment: Thanks your comment really helped me to appraise how I was approaching the problem. Indeed, I am avoiding throwing the kitchen sink, and I am not passing the buck.

Answer (score 1):

How about introducing a generic Action class that can be subclassed:

```
public class Action {
    public void runWithHandlers() throws Exception {
        try {
           run();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw CustomException.programmer_error(e);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            throw new CustomException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw CustomException.unexpected_error(e);
        }
    }
    public void run() throws Exception {
        // TODO subclasses of Action must implement this
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else in your code you instantiate one of the subclasses of Action and call runWithHandlers():

```
new MyAction().runWithHandlers();
```

Comment: Good answer. But I'll give it to the guy who suggested the Strategy pattern I think. This is similar, and frankly I prefer it (it's simpler), but I think it's sensible to point other people towards something more readily named.

Comment: My solution actually has a name: It's the well-known Template method pattern, right from the GoF book :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford Scala, check it out: you can pattern match the exception in the catch block.  See [Scala for Java Refugees Part 4: Pattern Matching and Exceptions](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-4).