# How do I add state information without writing repetitive code when catching multiple Java exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I've read a few other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272714/java-how-to-avoid-duplicating-complicated-catch-blocks) about avoiding repetition in Java `catch` blocks.  Apparently, what I *really* want is "multi-catch", but seeing as Java 7 isn't here yet, is there a good pattern to let me add state to my exceptions, then re-throw them, without [catching the kitchen sink](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html)?

Specifically, I have some code that makes library calls, which can throw exceptions, but don't provide nearly enough context for successful debuging.  I find myself having a problem, then going in, wrapping the library call in a try/catch, catching the specific exception, then adding extra state information in the `catch` block and re-throwing the caught exception.  I then re-iterate through that loop over and over, each time finding a new error condition to log.  I wind up with

```
try {
  make_library_call();
}
catch (SomeException e){
  throw new SomeException ("Needed local state information is " + importantInfo, e);
}
catch (SomeOtherException e){
  throw new SomeOtherException ("Needed local state information is " + importantInfo, e);
}
catch (YetAnotherException e){
  throw new YetAnotherException ("Needed local state information is " + importantInfo, e);
}
```

etc etc.  I think what I'd really like to see is more along the lines of

```
try {
  make_lib_call();
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.AddSomeInformationSomehow("Needed Info" + importantInfo);
  throw e;
}
```

assuming that in that case `e` would keep its actual runtime type when re-thrown -- in this case, even catching unchecked would probably be OK since I'd be re-throwing them, and they'd benefit from carrying the extra state info as well.  I guess an alternate might be something like

```
try{
  make_lib_call();
}
finally {
  if (/*an exception happened*/)
    logger.debug("Some state info: " + importantInfo);
}
```

but I don't know how to write the conditional.  Is that crazy / wrong?

Comment: If you were to do the rethrow as you suggest, your method would have to have `throws Exception`.  It couldn't be any narrower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably expecting this, but **no**, there isn't a *good* (and by good I mean clean) way to do this.  You're probably expecting it because you subconsciously knew that if there was a good pattern for doing this, it probably wouldn't have been worth adding to Java 7.

It's actually the [final rethrow](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/better-exception-handling-in-java-7-multicatch-and-final-rethrow/) feature that you'd find really handy in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For the alternative:

```
boolean isOk = false;
try{
  make_lib_call();
  isOk = true;
}
finally {
  if (!isOk)
    logger.debug("Some state info: " + importantInfo);
}
```

Comment: You're *correct*, I just wish this wasn't the answer -- I thought of this, but it's a little ham-fisted.  It feels like something I'd do in C :(